# Overriding `Function.prototype.toString` in JSDOM for a specific function

Tags: function, mocking, prototype, jsdom

I'm using JSDOM and trying to mock the behavior of window.Function.prototype.toString.call(window.WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getParameter). I want it to return 'function getParameter() { [native code] }' instead of the actual source code of the getParameter function.

I have a class WebGLRenderingContext where the getParameter function is defined:

```js
export class WebGLRenderingContext {
    // ...

    getParameter(paramId: number) {
        // Implementation...
    }
}

window.WebGLRenderingContext = WebGLRenderingContext;
```

I have attempted to override the toString method directly on the getParameter function:

```js
WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getParameter.toString = function () {
    return 'function getParameter() { [native code] }';
};
```

This works when calling WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getParameter.toString(), but it does not have the desired effect when calling window.Function.prototype.toString.call(window.WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getParameter). The latter returns the actual source code of the function instead of the mocked string.

In order to globally change the behavior of Function.prototype.toString, I tried to override it and add a conditional check for the specific getParameter function:

```js
const originalToString = Function.prototype.toString;

Function.prototype.toString = function () {
    const str = originalToString.call(this);
    if (str.includes('getParameter(paramId)')) {
        return 'function getParameter() { [native code] }';
    }
    return str;
};
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as expected and still returns the original source code of the getParameter function when calling window.Function.prototype.toString.call(window.WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getParameter).

I am looking for a way to change the return value of Function.prototype.toString for the specific getParameter function in the context of JSDOM, while leaving (for expections of some) all other functions unaffected.

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated!